# Why can you calculate the potential near the surface of a conducting sphere by acting as though there is a point charge at the center of the sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

When you want to calculate the potential at the surface of the sphere, you can just use kq/r, r being the radius of the sphere. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The deep reason is a combination of Gauss's law, which states that the surface integral of the flux of the electric field around a closed surface is determined by the charge enclosed, and spherical symmetry, which renders the surface integral trivial. Combining these facts tells you that the electric field (and hence potential) is determined by the total charge enclosed in the sphere -- regardless of exactly how the charge is arranged (so long as the distribution is spherically symmetric).

If you don't trust Gauss's law, you can also do the problem explicitly. You can calculate the potential at point $r$ by integrating the potential $k dq/r$ from each charge element on the surface of the sphere. If you do this, you'll find that the potential at $r$ "magically" turns out to be the same as if the charge was located at the center of the sphere. In fact, this calculation is halfway to a proof of Gauss's law, and is worth doing.